# MPAndroidChart hide background grid

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I'm using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) - LineChart in my android application. I want to remove gridlines from the background . How can I remove gridlines from the background?

[image: MPAndroidChart Line Chart Example]

Library: [MPAndroidChart on GitHub](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

**EDIT:** I created my own custom LineChart using this library. I want to remove bottom line. how can I do that too?
[image: Custom LineChart]

Comment: how you have removed values from nodes ?

Comment: @HiteshSahu use lineData.setDrawValues(false)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Use this:

```
mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
mChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
```

Please note you may need right axis or both of them. It depends on axis you are actually using.

**UPDATE:**
Is it axis line? If it is, then simply `chart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false)`

Also possible: `chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false)`

Comment: @philipp-jahoda Do you know if we can change grid color to alternate between white and grey

Comment: @Philipp How to remove the horizontal axis

Comment: Turn off the horizontal grid lines by using:      mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);

Comment: Is it possible to remove or keep some of the grids among all?

Answer (score 14):

Simply below three lines remove horizontal and vertical lines in the bar chart.
[image]

```
barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
barChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
```

[image]

Comment: how to remove barChart of outer line  ?

Comment: @PrinceDholakiya

use below code for remove outer line:

barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);

barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);

barChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);

Answer (score 12):

Use this code to clear all lines with labels:

```
mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
mChart.setClickable(false);
mChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
mChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);

mChart.setDrawBorders(false);
mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);

mChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
mChart.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);
mChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);

mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
```

and use this to remove value of all points:

```
LineDataSet set1;
set1.setDrawValues(false);
```

Comment: I was looking for all this. Nice one! :D

Answer (score 11):

Non of the above helped me to hide all axis lines. I just needed clean sheet with bars.
Code below did the work:

```
    barChart.xAxis.isEnabled = false
    barChart.axisLeft.isEnabled = false
    barChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
```

provided in kotlin, in java methods will look like that: `setEnabled(false)`

Answer (score 9):

Hide Background grid

```
    chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    chart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
```

Comment: What about the line at the top?

Answer (score 0):

to remove borders from chart you can use setDrawBorder(boolean) property.

`chart.setDrawBorders(false);`

Answer (score 0):

**code for removing outer line:**

```
barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false); 

barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false); 

barChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(false);
```

**code for removing gridline**

```
barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);

barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);

barChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
```