# How to remove grid lines behind the bars in HorizontalBarChart?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I want to remove background lines at every interval displayed. Tried with this but no use.
dailyTargetChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

```
XAxis xl = dailyTargetChart.getXAxis();
                        xl.setDrawAxisLine(true);
                        xl.setDrawGridLines(false);

                        YAxis yl = dailyTargetChart.getAxisLeft();
                        yl.setDrawAxisLine(true);
                        yl.setDrawGridLines(true);

                        YAxis yr = dailyTargetChart.getAxisRight();
                        yr.setDrawAxisLine(true);
                        yr.setDrawGridLines(false);
```

Tried this also but vertical lines are still visible at intervals

Comment: You mean this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263332/6774854 ?

Comment: Yes both horizontal and vertical lines behind the bars

Comment: XAxis xl = dailyTargetChart.getXAxis();
                        xl.setDrawAxisLine(true);
                        xl.setDrawGridLines(false);

                        YAxis yl = dailyTargetChart.getAxisLeft();
                        yl.setDrawAxisLine(true);
                        yl.setDrawGridLines(true);

                        YAxis yr = dailyTargetChart.getAxisRight();
                        yr.setDrawAxisLine(true);
                        yr.setDrawGridLines(false); have tried with all these but still vertical lines are visible

Comment: At intervals? You mean during animation or user input?

Comment: after animation ,after values are assigned  intervals means the labels which are seen on the axis lines like example 100,200,300

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
 horizontalBarChart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);
 horizontalBarChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
 horizontalBarChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
It will remove the barchart bar background line.

chart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false); // disable grid lines for the XAxis
chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false); // disable grid lines for the left YAxis
chart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false); // disable grid lines for the right YAxis